# C# Signaling two threads with AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading, autoresetevent, waitone

I need to create a program that counts to 10 using two threads.
one threads should print even numbers and the other should print odd numbers.
These threads should print the numbers in order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...)

I have done this code but it seems not to work... any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static AutoResetEvent autoEvent;
        private static int num = 10;

        static void DoWork(object data)
        {
            var counter = (int)data;

            if (counter == 1)
            {
                autoEvent.WaitOne();
            }

            while (counter <= num)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(counter);
                counter += 2;
                autoEvent.Set();
                autoEvent.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            var evenCounter = new Thread(DoWork);
            evenCounter.Start(0);

            var notEvenCounter = new Thread(DoWork);
            notEvenCounter.Start(1);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "but it seems not to work."   can u give more explanation

Comment: I meant that the printed numbers are not ordered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that code `autoEvent.WaitOne()` may not block because the `AutoResetEvent` is already in signaled state:

```
        autoEvent.Set();
        autoEvent.WaitOne();
```

So that thread will not wait for another thread as you planned.
To solve that problem you need to use 2 `AutoResetEvent`s. One thread will wait on the first `AutoResetEvent`, second thread will wait on the second `AutoResetEvent`. Each thread will signal an `AutoResetEvent` that 'belongs' to another thread.
To demonstrate my idea I'll show you the lines of code only where you need to make a change:

```
private static AutoResetEvent autoEvents[] = new AutoResetEvent[2];
```

...

```
autoEvents[0] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
autoEvents[1] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

...

```
var counter = (int)data;
int initial_counter = counter;
```

...

```
if (counter == 1)
{
autoEvents[initial_counter].WaitOne();
}
```

...

```
autoEvents[1 - initial_counter].Set();
autoEvents[initial_counter].WaitOne();
```

At the end of DoWork signal the appropriate `AutoResetEvent` to avoid infinite blocking of another thread:

```
autoEvents[1 - initial_counter].Set();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here seems to be your problem:

```
   autoEvent.Set();
   autoEvent.WaitOne();
```

You set the lock free and then immediately wait for the lock, which will lead to arbitrary execution patterns.

I suggest you use 2 locks, so one thread can block the other.

Comment: I have tried  this  code ant it's work what u  mean by 2 locks can u give an example

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Thread t1 = new Thread(Method1);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(Method2);
            t1.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            t2.Start();
            t1.Join();
            t2.Join();
            _autoEvent1.Close();
            _autoEvent2.Close();
        }

        private static void Method1()
        {

            do
            {
               _autoEvent2.WaitOne();

                if (!SharedCode(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
                {
                    break;
                }

                _autoEvent1.Set();
            } while (true);
        }

        private static void Method2()
        {
            do
            {
                _autoEvent1.WaitOne();
                //_autoEvent2.Set();
                if (!SharedCode(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))
                    break;
                _autoEvent2.Set();
            } while (true);
        }

        private static bool SharedCode(int threadId)
        {
           lock (_lockObject)
            {

                Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
                if (_count > 10)
                    return false;
                Console.WriteLine("ThreadId={0} , count={1}", threadId,_count);
            }

            return true;
        }
        private  static AutoResetEvent _autoEvent1 = new AutoResetEvent(true);
        private static AutoResetEvent _autoEvent2 = new AutoResetEvent(true);
        private static Object _lockObject = new object();
        private static int _count = 0;
    }
}
```